# Variable input for LSTM for multivariate time series in Keras

Tags: variables, input, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Using Keras, I want to train an RNN (with an LSTM cell) on a batch of size N, with K timesteps and a vector of size L for each timestep (The decoder output is one vector of size L).

Sadly, I have troubles in making it work for different sizes of timesteps, i.e., for different K.

There are 2 problems related to this:

1. Whenever I try to create a 3D-tensor with numpy I get the type: array(list(array())) instead of type: array(array(array())), since my second dimension is not fixed. The resulting shape is then (N,) and not (N, -1, L)
2. I found out that padding is one solution for univariate time series, but I have vectors for each time step of size L with `L>>1`. In addition the shape from (1) does not fit, even though I used:

   model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(N, None, L)))    // None for different K

Or is the only solution to call the fit-method N times with every single batch instance?

Do you have any idea, how to solve my problem?

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to pad the data array to maximum timestep length

```
from keras.preprocessing import sequence

data_array=sequence.pad_sequences(data_array,maxlen=max_K)
```

Also do not pass the batch size with the input_shape

```
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(max_K, L)))
```

Comment: But isn't padding a solution for univariate values? 
Like: [1,2,3,4] -> [1,2,3,4,0,0,0].
In my case its multivariate data:
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

Comment: [ [ [1,2],[1,3],[1,4] ] , [ [1,5],[1,6] ] ]  -> [ [ [1,2],[1,3],[1,4] ],  [ **[0,0]**,[1,5],[1,6]]]

Comment: Yeah, tried it aswell. Seems to work :) Thanks a lot! Hope my definition of the masking layer to ignore the padding is correct:
model.add(Masking(mask_value=np.zeros(dim_attributes), input_shape=(dim_timesteps, dim_attributes)))